# Using VLC command line to stream video

Tags: java, servlets, streaming, vlc

I need to run a webserver that will stream video using rtsp. I am thinking of having a Java servlet that will process video requests, and then use the vlc command line interface to stream the video.

I got rtsp streaming working in VLC using the gui interface, but since I want the servlet to execute VLC on requests I need to use the commandline interface. I haven't found a good tutorial on this, and most of the commands I've found haven't worked.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh my bad, I wasn't aware of such a thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Red5 - It's an open source (read:free) java based RTMP and there is an RTSP plug in you can use.

I've used it and it's great!

http://www.red5.org/

Comment: One question about red5, will the video metadata be thrown out during the streaming process? Because I need the metadata to be preserved

Answer (score 0):

Run darwin streaming server and lightpd on Ubuntu 10.04.  Use VLC to stream using rtsp just by providing the IP address to the server.

vlc rtsp://x.x.x.x/file.mp4

Slightly more complicated but that's the basic recipe.